# How do I write a Rails finder method to search for my model where the has_many has no particular attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, finder

I'm using Rails 5.  I have the following model ...

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :photos, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy, :as => :photo, :inverse_of => :photo
```

I realize that if I want to search for cities with no photos, I can write this finder ...

```
City.includes(:photos).where(photos: { city_id: nil })
```

but what if I want to search for cities that have no photos where the photo's extension attribute is "JPG"?

Comment: If a city has no photos, how can there be an extension attribute of "JPG" on nothing? Not quite following the question entirely

Comment: My quesiton isn't how do I find a city with no photos, it's how do I find a city with no photos that have an extension of "JPG."  It's fine if a city has photos that have extensions other than "JPG."

Comment: `City.left_outer_joins(:photos).where("photos.extension != 'JPG' OR photos.city_id IS NULL")`

Comment: Thanks @max.  Is there any performance gain in your answer compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: You would have to run explain on the queries but my money is on that this is faster than the subquery in the excepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give all the cities which don't have `JPG` or no photos

```
City.where.not(id: Photo.select(:city_id).where(extension: 'JPG'))
```